# How to make declared statements from form1_load available in private functions?

Tags: vb.net

In my form1_load I declare:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load



    Dim name As Integer

    'Lave boardet med to forloops

    For j = 0 To 7
        For i = 0 To 7



            'Definerer boardet
            Dim btn As New PictureBox
```

But when I try to use the declared "btn" in a function, it says "btn is not declared, it may be inaccessible due to its protection level". Is there a way to make the things I wrote in form1_load accessible?

Comment: Why is this tagged `vba` when it's actually VB.net?

Comment: My mistake - thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

No. Stuff declared within a method is local to that method.

Declare things common to all methods as class members.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!